# Chrome Shows Skull and Crossbones

Tags: macos, google-chrome

If I go to http://developer.apple.com and then click on "Member Center," Chrome (OSX) shows a skull and crossbones in the URL. Some of the resources are not secure. When I look at the source to the page, most of the scripts have the `http:` prefix instead of `https:`... Is MY Chrome broken, or is Chrome broken, or do Google and Apple disagree on what's secure?

I have removed all extensions from Chrome, but the situation is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means Apple's page is broken. What you're getting is known as a "mixed content warning". It simply means some of the page's resources weren't loaded via SSL and some were.

It is basically equivalent to this well known IE dialog:

[image]

And this less prominent one you may know from Firefox (padlock):

[image]

This is Chrome's old one, which they've changed because it didn't stand out very well:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not just you, if you double click on the icon, it states:

[image]

Apple are using content from a non encrypted source on the secure page making this error show up.

Comment: Great. I was getting worried.